# How to use promptbox to change background color?

Tags: javascript

I found another post but it wasn't using a promptbox. I just need the exact same functionality as this but using a promptbox:

```
function changeBackground() {
    var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    document.bgColor = color;
}

document.getElementById("submitColor").addEventListener("click", changeBackground, false);
```

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) might help?

Comment: Well what if it didn't help... I consulted google multiple times and saw the exact same link you have posted.

Comment: There's a bunch of examples on the linked page, just apply them for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get the value of a prompt

`var color = prompt("What color");`

and this to set the background:

`document.bgColor = color;`

Now color will be whatever the user inputs.

Those two lines of code do the same thing as the above.

Thanks to @OliverRqdini heres a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ff614fh)

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I put the "if else" for no reason, I thought it was mandatory because all the prompt boxes I have been told to place in exercises had them.

Comment: @CodingIsHardPlsHelp `if..else` is not mandatory, but you can validate the value user entered to the promp box by using that. Please show the code you really have, you might get rid of some down votes.